# Web interface Xcode 9 Bots

Tags: xcode, xcode-server

Before when I was using xcode server to integrate project I have some web interface to display if bots was sucesfull or not.

[It's a figure 7-1 from here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/MonitorBotsandDownloadProductsfromaWebBrowser.html)

Now  I see this option is not fully dead but it's definetly doesn't work well. So I can see the option in context menu here to point out to a browser.

[image]

but when I do that it's only shows:

[image]

And in new server there is no Xcode tab even.

Anyone know it's still possible to have web interface for bots in Xcode?

Comment: any updates on this?  i am seeing this as an issue as well

Answer (score 0):

What fixed it for me was to uncheck "Using Server app on a remote Mac" within the macOS Server app and rebooting the server. The checkbox is located in the main section of the Server app in the "Settings" tab.

Comment: As a workaround, you could connect to the Mac using vnc and run the server app locally until Apple fixes this.